# How can I write a python unit test to check that a certain line is there, and if not then an attribute error is thrown?

Tags: python, unit-testing

So I have a large function `pass1()`:

```
def g_control(...): 
    <some line here that makes stats.invalid_currency a valid call)


def pass1(...): 
    ...
    stats = g_control(...) 
    
    if stats.invalid_currency(..): 
        raise Exception('Something is missing in g_conrol')
```

I want to write a unit test that ensures that inside `g_control` that we have that one particular line, and if not, then `stats.invalid_currency` would throw an Exception saying that `stats has no attribute invalid currency`.

how can I do this?

Comment: I've liked the @alec_djinn answer, because he showed the it is possible. But when we are using a unit test, we are trying to teste a piece of code. It means that this code is available there in that time. We test the result of that portion of code executed. If you may have an absence of code, then the unit test are not the better approach for you.

Comment: Take a look at this question and answers https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/439397/what-are-best-practices-for-testing-the-absence-of-functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module for this

Here is a toy example:

```
def func():
    x = 2+3 #line to check
    if x > 3:
        return True
```

Then in your test code you can do something like this:

```
import inspect

line_to_check = "x = 2+3"
lines = inspect.getsource(func)
assert line_to_check in lines
```